# rewrite condition for localization

Tags: regex, apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following type of URLs,

```
foo.com/en-us/
foo.com/fr-fr/
```

The URLS can also be:

```
foo.com/en-us/index.html
foo.com/en-us/anything/anything/index.html
```

I would like to rewrite and redirect to lowercase versions like :

```
foo.com/en-US/ 
to 
foo.com/en-us/
```

or

```
foo.com/en-Us/
to
foo.com/en-us/
```

or

```
foo.com/EN-us/
to
foo.com/en-us/
```

I tried variations of following but no luck.

`^.*\/[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}\/.*` doens't cover these cases

it does cover: `foo.com/EN-US/index.html`

What would be the rewrite condition and rule for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `RewriteMap` and rewrite rule to redirect to lowercase `/<lang>-<country>` URLs:

```
# RewriteMap to convert any string to lowercase
# This cannot be used in .htaccess
RewriteMap lc int:tolower

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[a-z-]*[A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})(/.*)?$ /${lc:$1}$2 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

Here `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[a-z-]*[A-Z]` is used to ensure there is at least one capital letter in first part.

Comment: How can I make it more general to include `fr-fr` , `it-it` or any country?

Comment: Check my updated answer. To make it totally generic you will need to use `RewriteMap`. For that you need to have access to Apache server config. Do you have it?

Comment: Yes, i have access to httpd.conf.

Comment: I tried: `RewriteMap lc int:tolower
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\/[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2}\/.*
#RewriteRule . ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]` but no luck.

Comment: can you also please cover something like /en-Us/index.html

Comment: My rule already covers `/en-Us/index.html` kind of cases. I have added `RewriteMap` based rule to make it totally generic.

Answer (score 0):

You should include lower case letters in your regex. Try using this as regex:

```
^.*\/[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2}+.*
```